# "Transpose" data frame without for loops

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, tidyr

I'm not really trying to transpose a data frame, per se. But what I'm trying to achieve is something similar.

I have a (very large) data frame of the form:

```
variable    country         iso     2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2014
Var1        Argentina       ARG     67.3    65      63.6    60.4    56.6    54.4    57.3
Var2        Argentina       ARG     196.785 196.918 207.487 209.596 219.171 216.852 213.124
Var1        Austria         AUT     97.3    95      63.6    60.4    56.6    54.4    57.3
Var2        Austria         AUT     296.785 396.918 207.487 209.596 219.171 216.852 213.124
```

and so on for many variables, years and countries.

I want to get it in the form:

`country     iso     year           Var1        Var2`
`Argentina   ARG     2007           67.3        196.785`
`Argentina   ARG     2008           65          196.918`
.
.
`Austria     AUT     2007           97.3        296.785`
`Austria     AUT     2008           95          396.918`

and so on..

Is there any clean way to do this without resorting to for loops etc.??

I'm thinking there must be some variation of the dplyr `merge` function that can accomplish this, but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tidyr can do this for you. Use `gather` and `spread`. It pays a lot to learn these two very well, check out the example:

```
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
    variable = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var1", "Var2"),
     country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Austria", "Austria"),
         iso = c("ARG", "ARG", "AUT", "AUT"),
       X2007 = c(67.3, 196.785, 97.3, 296.785),
       X2008 = c(65, 196.918, 95, 396.918),
       X2009 = c(63.6, 207.487, 63.6, 207.487),
       X2010 = c(60.4, 209.596, 60.4, 209.596),
       X2011 = c(56.6, 219.171, 56.6, 219.171),
       X2012 = c(54.4, 216.852, 54.4, 216.852),
       X2014 = c(57.3, 213.124, 57.3, 213.12)
)

df1 %>% gather(Year, Value, -c(variable:iso)) %>% 
      spread(variable, Value)
```

Read-up the vignette to get a better handle on how it works.